# Random Matrix Generation with range of Eigenvalues, using Eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

I am generating some random matrix $A$ via [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix):

$$
A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}
$$

where $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_i)$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$ and $Q=[v_1, \dots,v_n]$ is a matrix composed of eigenvectors of $A$. 
This way, $\lambda_i$ can be chosen to be in $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to some random distribution, e.g. uniform. Let $Q$ be some full rank matrix.

How does one guarantee $A$ to be real ($A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$), instead of complex ($A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$) while maintaining complex eigenvalues?

Comment: It suffices to ensure that real eigenvalues have real eigenvectors and complex eigenvalues are selected in conjugate pairs so that if $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair, then so is $(\bar \lambda, \bar v)$ where $\bar \lambda$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda$ and $\bar v$ is the vector whose entries are the complex conjugates to those of $v$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. I will code it this way. Do you have a reason why it works, if it does that is ;).

Comment: It is easy to show that any real matrix will have the properties I describe. It's a little tricker to show that any matrix with these properties is real, but I strongly suspect that any matrix with these properties will indeed be real.

Comment: Real matrices will always have characteristic polynomials with real coefficients. Those will always have either real roots or complex conjugate pairs. 
The pair-ness of the eigenvectors then follow from arguments about complex symmetry of $Av=\lambda v$ and $A\bar{v} = \bar{\lambda} \bar{v}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To back up the method outlined in my comment:

> **Claim:** Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable with the property that for any real eigenvalue $\lambda$ there is a real eigenvector, and for any complex eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ we also have the conjugate $(\bar \lambda, \bar v)$.  Then $A$ must be a real matrix.

**Proof:** Let $x$ be an arbitrary real vector.  It suffices to show that $Ax$ is also real.

$x$ can be written as a linear combination (with real coefficients) of eigenvectors associated with real eigenvalues and of sums $v + \bar v$ where $v$ is an eigenvector associated with a complex eigenvalue.

It suffices then to note that for any complex eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$, we have
$$
A(v + \bar v) = \lambda v + \bar \lambda \bar v = \lambda v + \overline{\lambda v} \in \Bbb R^n.
$$
We may now conclude that $Ax$ will also be a real linear combination of these real vectors.